# Add missing permissions to a specific AppPool identity to allow calling CreateProcessWithLogonW from ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, permissions

**TL;DR**: I need to call `CreateProcessWithLogonW` from my IIS-hosted ASP.NET application in order to call an external executable under a different account and delegate a job to it. How can I do this?

---

The reason I can't simply use `Process.Start` API is that the external executable has a number of COM dependencies that need to be configured. This entails making sure a number of registry entries are there and that the account has required launch and activation permissions which need to be set via DCOM config. Suffice to say this has proven quite unmanageable to do for each of the AppPool identities on every server we have.

The idea is to create a single additional interactive account on each system, configure it as necessary, and then test that the external executable can be successfully run by hand.

The problem now becomes how to start this executable from ASP.NET app and have it run under the new account (just the executable, not the whole ASP.NET app!).

Simply calling `CreateProcessWithLogonW` results in "Access denied" error, which I've been told is the consequence of the AppPool identity's under-privileged nature.

I've been searching the internet and I've seen a lot of answers on how to grant file-system permissions to AppPool identities. Nothing about permissions for `CreateProcessWithLogonW`, however, short of changing the identity to something else.

But I'm still wondering if there is a way to configure the AppPool identity for this?

I don't feel comfortable changing the identity to `Local Service` or `Local System` as has been suggested elsewhere. I'm worried it could enable unknown additional permissions that are not really needed by the ASP.NET app, which could in turn change the security implications of a rather large code base.

I admit I'm probably having a *"Here be dragons!!!"* type of reaction to identity changing, but I'm also honestly wondering why I couldn't simply add one additional permission to an existing identity instead?

Comment: Changing the identity to `LocalSystem` won't work anyway, because `CreateProcessWithLogonW` explicitly documents that this will not work, and the reason why may offer some insight as to why the IIS app pool identity can't do it (and what you might try instead): "You cannot call `CreateProcessWithLogonW` from a process that is running under the "LocalSystem" account, because the function uses the logon SID in the caller token, and the token for the "LocalSystem" account does not contain this SID. As an alternative, use the `CreateProcessAsUser` and `LogonUser` functions."

Comment: @JeroenMostert: LogonUser + DuplicateToken + CreateProcessAsUser combo was the first thing I tried. I gave up after not being able to make it work even in a standalone console app test, running under admin account. CreateProcessAsUser always threw "Access denied". I admit I might have done something wrong, I'm not sure anymore, tbh. CreateProcessWithLogonW *did* work in the same console app test, however, so I wanted to make it work under ASP.NET as well.

Comment: `CreateProcessAsUser` is harder to use because it additionally requires asserting a privilege (or two). You could try making the ASP.NET process identity a simple, interactive, local account (not an admin, not LocalSystem). Per the docs of CPAU, `CreateProcessWithLogonW` does not actually require special privileges; the reason it won't work with `LocalSystem` (and possibly other identities that aren't logged on interactively, like the default app pool identities) appear to be of another nature, which I'm not sure can be resolved by tweaking a security token here or there.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: I'm pretty confident your proposed solution would work, yes. I'm just not happy about the fact that Windows' permission model is this limited. In that case, I'd rather make a clean separation of concerns here and isolate the functionality into a separate local service, where I can more tightly control the actual API calls. Thanks for the helpful reassurance! If you feel like it, you can post your suggestion as an answer and I will accept it!